# Why do I keep getting MySQL Client Out of Memory error after a certain period of time...?

Tags: c++, mysql

I'm developing a server application that preforms various (probably hundreds to thousands) of MySQL Queries a day (SELECTS, INSERTS, & UPDATES).

The querying works great, until....

For some reason after the Server has been up for roughly 1 to 2 days it generates a MySQL Error any time I try to preform any MySQL Query from the Server... The Server was developed using C++.

The error says that The MySQL Client has run out of memory.

I'm Using
MySQL Community Server 5.6.24

Is there some kind of hidden cache of data stored in memory that I don't know about that gets occupied anytime a MySQL Query gets executed....? That's the only thing I can think of.

Comment: Could you be more specific with the client library you're using? Or even better, provide some code of your application?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably related to the queries you're using.
Indexing can help as well as limiting the results returned from these queries.
I'm guessing you're loading a certain amount of data using `SELECT` commands and the returned values need to be stored somewhere, which is the memory.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/out-of-memory.html

This link offers some possible solutions.

> To remedy the problem, first check whether your query is correct. Is it reasonable that it should return so many rows? If not, correct the query and try again. Otherwise, you can invoke mysql with the --quick option. This causes it to use the mysql_use_result() C API function to retrieve the result set, which places less of a load on the client (but more on the server).

---

Also if you have enough RAM you could try to increase the memory limit in the config file.

To be more specific this is what you want to adjust:

`InnoDB` Settings

> innodb_buffer_pool_size - Defaults to 128M. This is the main setting you want to change, since it sets how much memory InnoDB will use for data+indexes loaded into memory. For a dedicated MySQL server, the recommended size is 50-80% of installed memory. So for example, a server with 64G of RAM should have around a 50G buffer pool.
>
> The danger of setting this value too high is that there will be no memory left for the operating system and some MySQL-subsystems that rely on filesystem cache such as binary logs, and InnoDB's transaction logs.

Taken from:

http://www.tocker.ca/2013/09/17/what-to-tune-in-mysql-56-after-installation.html

---

Another possibility is that something in the c++ code is not allocating the memory and after it's done deallocating the memory properly.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing that could be leaking is connections.  Database connections are very expensive, and hang around.  I googled "mysql connection pooling".  If you're using Connector/J, you could look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-usagenotes-j2ee-concepts-connection-pooling.html, and if you're using connector/net you could try http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-connection-pooling.html.